# nested template types

Tags: c++, templates, types

I want to require a template type to be a templates type:

```
template < template < int beta, typename gamma> class alpha >
gamma foo()
{
    // do stuff with beta, gamma
    gamma c[beta]; 
    alpha a();
    alpha b();
}
```

I want to have gamma and beta decided by the values I give, so:

```
foo< hello<2,double> >()
```

will create a `hello<2,double>` object instead of `alpha`, and `c` will be an array of `double` with 2 elements.

So, I want to extract the template parameters from the templated class passed to foo.

How would I do this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Also, `alpha a();` declares a function and not an object. Do you really meant that?

Comment: I'm confused by the 1 in your code snippet and the 2 in the subsequent one.  You might have a typo there?

Comment: alpha is a template class, and you want to extract the template parameter of alpha in a function, is that what you want?

Comment: @iammilind alpha is the type, a() is the constructor, right?

Comment: @weidi: yes!, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Andrew Spott: No, that's not a "constructor". `alpha a();` is a function declaration: a function `a` that takes no arguments and returns `alpha` object. If you want a default-constructed object, lose the `()`: `alpha a;`.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, No. You should google about "most vexing parse". In your code `a` is a declaration of function named `a`, returning `alpha`, with no argument.

Comment: @AndreyT:  Thanks, this is a simplified example, and I forgot that particular detail.  I'll fix it, but it isn't super relevant to my question (just that alpha is a class).

Comment: @iammilind:  Thanks, I've read about the "most vexing parse", I had just forgotten about it.

Answer (score 4):

The template declaration you provided take a so called template-template parameter (a template parameter of template type). Yet the example of usage you provided attempts to pass an "ordinary" class as an argument (once all template parameters are fixed, template class turns into an "ordinary" class, it is no longer a template).

This immediately means that template-template parameter is not what you need. Template-template parameters serve a completely different purpose. (I won't go into details here).

One possible solution for your problem is to require the argument classes to expose their template arguments through nested types and constants. I.e. your `hello` template must contain a nested constant `beta_value` and nested typename `gamma_type`

```
template <int BETA, typename GAMMA> class hello 
{
public:
  static const int beta_value = BETA;
  typedef GAMMA gamma_type;
  ...
};
```

In this case your function will be declared with ordinary type template parameter

```
template <typename ALPHA> typename ALPHA::gamma_type foo()
{
   // do stuff with beta, gamma
   typename ALPHA::gamma_type c[ALPHA::beta_value]; 
   ALPHA a();
   ALPHA b();
}
```

If some user forget to follow the convention, the compiler will refuse to compile `foo` and force that user to update the definition of their argument class.